# Rotate a batch of images using `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate`

Tags: python, scipy, rotation, batch-processing, ndimage

Let's suppose that `X` is a `numpy.ndarray` tensor that holds a set of color images. For instance, `X`'s shape is `(100, 3, 32, 32)`; i.e., we have 100 32x32 rgb images (such as those provided by the CIFAR dataset).

I want to rotate the images in `X` and I found out that this could be done using the [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html#scipy-ndimage-interpolation-rotate) function of scipy.

However, I can do it correctly only for a single image and a single color channel each time, while I would like to apply the function for all images and all color channels at once.

What I tried and it works so far is the following:

```
import scipy.ndimage.interpolation

image = X[0,0,:,:]
rotated_image = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(input=image, angle=45, reshape=False)
```

but what I want to do, which could look like this

```
X_rot = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(input=X, angle=45, reshape=False)
```

does not work.

Is there any way to apply `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate` for a batch of images like the numpy.ndarray tensor `X`?

In any case, is there any better way to rotate a batch of images (stored in a `numpy.ndarray`) efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-liner,

```
import scipy.ndimage.interpolation as intrp

rotated_imgs = [intrp.rotate(input=img, angle=45, reshape=False) for img in X]
```

assumed your X has the more standard shape `(n_images, w, h, color_channels)`.

If you want to get your hands on matrices, I suggest you to generate your rotation matrix with `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D`, replicate/stack it along the first axis, and then apply it to your `X`, but it can get complicated without `cv2.warpAffine`, which takes a single image as input.